# jquery FB.api function

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I would like to get the post insights for every post in my feed. I can't to pass the parameters from the function. This is the code:

```
function load_post(page_id, tok)
  {      
  var data = { 
               access_token : tok,
              };
  FB.api("/" + page_id + "/feed?fields=id,name",'get',data ,function (response) {
    if (response && !response.error) {  
        console.log(response);
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {

           var r = "";
           (function(post_id, data, r) {
              FB.api("/" + post_id + "/insights/post_impressions",'get',data ,function (response_insight) {  
                r = response_insight.data[0].values[0].value;
              });
           })(response.data[i].id, data, r);

           alert(r);
        }
     }

   });
}
```

I don't know where is the error. I'm new in jquery/javascript and I think is a function problem. Can you help me? Thanks a lot.

PS: my goal is to take response_insight.data[0].values[0].value value

this is the response_insight response:

```
data: Array[1]
0: Object
    description: "Lifetime: The number of impressions of your Page post. (Total Count)"
    id: "my_id_post/insights/post_impressions/lifetime"
    name: "post_impressions"
    period: "lifetime"
    title: "Lifetime Post Total Impressions"
values: Array[1]
0: Object
value: 676
```

Comment: are you got the  console.log(response); value ?

Comment: Yes I get the values (response and response_insight)

Comment: The problem is that I can't return the response_insight.data[0].values[0].value; from second fb.api function

Comment: pls share the response_insight output

Comment: I have edit the reponse

Comment: console.log(response_insight.data[1].values[1].value); try this

Comment: I get an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined. The insight metric "post_impressions/lifetime" return a single array dimension I think.

Comment: My question is: how can I pass the r variable from the second and first function?

Comment: Just add the return r; in after r variable assign

Comment: It doesn't works. I had put "return r" after "r = response_insight.data[0].values[0].value;"

Comment: console.log( response_insight.data[0].values[0].value); then what happen ?

Comment: I get a value (676). The problem is that I'm into FB.api "/feed" and I do the loop. For each loop I call FB.api "insights" because I would like to get the response_insight.data[0].values[0].value.

Comment: add the return r; and what return console.log(load_post()); code in outside of function

Comment: _“The problem is that I can't return the response_insight.data[0].values[0].value; from second fb.api function”_ – if that’s your main problem here, then this question is basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1427878